# filter the data in linq

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Currently I use EF to retrieve data from DB;

I want to merge 4 db connections into 1;

so I am using the following sql:

```
select 0 as text
union
select distinct channel        as text    from  CHARGE_ORDER
union
select 1 as text
union      
select distinct  packet_id     as text    from  CHARGE_ORDER
union
select 2 as text
union   
select distinct  recharge_type  as text    from  CHARGE_ORDER
union
select 3 as text
union  
select distinct   order_type    as text    from  CHARGE_ORDER
union
select 4 as text
```

then

```
var total = context.Database.SqlQuery<SelectDto>(totalSql).ToList();
```

I want to use Linq like this:(this is wrong)

```
dto.channelSelect = total.Where(x=>  "0"> x.text.Substring(0, 1) && x.text.Substring(0, 1) < "1").
```

but the text is string ,the Linq does't work;

I can  use method to get the data that I want

```
private List<SelectDto> PostHandle(List<SelectDto> list,string start,string end)
            {
                List<SelectDto> result = new List<SelectDto>();
                int len = list.Count;
                for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                {
                    if (list[i].text == start)
                    {
                        for(int j = i+1; j < len; j++)
                        {
                            if (list[j].text != end)
                            {
                                result.Add(list[j]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
             return result ;
            }
```

Is there a better way of handling this requirement?

maybe my question is not clear?

so people suggest me using skipwhile; but think skipWhile could not meet this need;

this is what I need; I don't whether have a better way to do

```
 var total = context.Database.SqlQuery<SelectDto>(totalSql).ToList();
            dto.channelSelect = PostHandleFilter(total, "0", "1");
            dto.packetSelect = PostHandleFilter(total, "1", "2");
            dto.chargeSelect = PostHandleFilter(total, "2", "3");
            dto.orderSelect = PostHandleFilter(total, "3", "4");
```

Comment: use `SkipWhile` in your linq query. ---  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075(v=vs.110).aspx. `dto.channelSelect = total.SkipWhile(x =>  x.text.Substring(0, 1) > "0" && x.text.Substring(0, 1) < "1")`

Comment: it does't work ,because text is string ;  string can't  compare with string

Comment: You should use the `String.Compare` method to compare string.  `dto.channelSelect = total.SkipWhile(x =>  string.Compare(x.text.Substring(0, 1),"0") >= 0 && string.Compare(x.text.Substring(0, 1),"1" <0)`

Comment: ok~thanks bro,it work

Comment: I've posted that answer now.

Comment: I think it could't work;~~~~